# when i try to start Kafka，I encounter this：No appenders could be found for logger (kafka.server.KafkaConfig)

Tags: log4j, apache-kafka

I had already copy log4j.properties to this folder like this ：

[image]

core-src-scala-log4j.properties

Comment: Can you post the content of your log4j file ? You would get this error if it is invalid/empty and also if the path you specified via `Dlog4j.configuration` is incorrect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: add vm options]

1. Edit configuraiton
2. in the vm options :  `-Dlog4j.configuration=file:config/log4j.properties`